# Round all elements in double array

Tags: c#, arrays

I need help trying to figure out how to round all the elements in a double array to 4 decimal places. I think I need to use either an `Array.ForEach` statement or a `foreach` statement, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

The Array has numbers (x/y coordinates) like this:

```
"0;24;5.99753782108473;21.770136316906;8.32805512530786;19.3909999184418"
```

These come from Autocad and can be up to 15 decimals long.  I only need a 1/16" accuracy for what I'm trying to do so I can round it to 4 decimals without hurting anything.

Currently I am rounding the value at the time I need it with `Math.Round(d1,4)` - d1 is the array name. However I think rounding the whole array at once would be "cleaner"

Comment: Usually rounding is for displaying purposes. Why round if its not necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the accuracy of 1/16-th, multiply your number by 16, round, and divide back by 16. Since 16 is a power of 2, `double` will provide a precise representation of it.

To convert the whole array at once, use LINQ: first, select the new value for each item, then convert the result back to an array, like this:

```
d1 = d1.Select(d => Math.Round(d*16) / 16).ToArray();
```

You need to use `System.Linq` in order for this to compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
 i think you can use foreach like this :
 double array_value
 foreach(Double arry in yourArray){
   array_value = Math.Round(arry,4);
 }
```